# Browserstack: Developer Tools for iPad?

Tags: browserstack

I am using Browserstack to test some websites on the iPad. I just don't seem to get where the developer tools are within that emulator. Shouldn't there be Firebug Lite somewhere? Can someone point the dev tools out to me please?

Answer (score 10):

Launch iOS simulator from BrowserStack.

Once loaded, from the OSX menu bar, click Help > Mac Help.

In the open window type "Safari" in the search box.

Click "Safari Overview".

Click "Open Safari for me".

From the Safari menu bar, click Develop > iOS Simulator > (the iOS tab you want to inspect)

[Screenshot of debugging iOS inside BrowserStack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyuKM.jpg)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work now. Can't find a way to open safari

Comment: This is working correctly, although a bit tricky. Not all versions of OSX will show "Safari Overview", but if you click around the help pages, you will eventually find a link that will open in Safari. I also noticed that in some versions, the console doesn't work at all, but iPad Pro with iOS 9 worked exactly as described in this answer.

Comment: This no longer works (at least not for the iPhone 5 simulator in Browserstack that I just tested).

Answer (score 7):

As I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39218700/195835), Browserstack now appears to support Dev Tools, but only on physical devices (those with a blue mobile icon, below).

[image: Browserstack launch]

You activate the dev tools by clicking the button in the toolbar:

[image: Browserstack Dev Tools Toolbar]

Answer (score 4):

In the iOS simulator you can click the 'bookmarks' button (of the device) and **firebug lite** is available from there. It does not seem to load on the iPhone 5 that I am testing currently but may work for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

To open Safari for debugging a simulator, follow the instructions above. If Safari Overview is not available, look for a "Search the Web" link at the bottom of the window.  This also opens Safari.