# How to open dev tools in iOS emulator on Browserstack?

Tags: html, ios, css, devtools, browserstack

I am using iPhone 6 emulator with iOS 8.3 on Browserstack and I need to inspect the source code of the website I am woking on.

**How do I open developer tools in iOS emulator on Browserstack?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Browserstack now appears to support Dev Tools, but only on physical devices (those with a blue mobile icon, below).

[image: Browserstack launch]

You activate the dev tools by clicking the button in the toolbar:

[image: Browserstack Dev Tools Toolbar]

As Alf Eaton mentioned in a comment below, some iOS devices now offer a choice of which browser to open (Chrome or Safari) – Dev Tools appears to only be available in Safari at the current time.

Comment: There is now also a choice of which browser to open, and Dev Tools is only available in Safari.

Answer (score 4):

I am Mukesh from BrowserStack. **Developer tools are not currently supported on iOS devices.** However, adding this support is on our list. We will keep you posted on developments.

Comment: What's the status here? The question remains unanswered.

Comment: Mukesh we have a bad bug on iPhones (5, 6) and need dev tools enabled to check errors. Any status on this?

Answer (score 0):

A full list of developer tools available on BrowserStack Live can be found here, for desktop OSes (Windows, MacOS): https://www.browserstack.com/developer-tools

For mobile, it is still only available on physical devices, as documented here: https://www.browserstack.com/question/660